# Lenovo X1 Thinkpad Yoga 3rd Ubuntu 22.04 login via fingerprints or camera

Tags: thinkpad, camera

I own Lenovo X1 Thinkpad Yoga 3rd. It looks like my hardware is not supported to login via fingerprints. After lsusb command there is nothing related with fingerprint. Is there any way to add this, I belive compilation will be needed?
Or maybe login via camera?
In 20.04 was not really efficient, working maybe 2 times out of 10.
Cheers

Comment: Out of curiosity have you run the Additional drivers tool to see if you have any hardware with no driver assigned? Can you please run lsusb and let me know if you see device: `Bus 001 Device 003: ID 06cb:00bd Synaptics, Inc.`. As well, make sure the firmware for your computer is up to date to ensure if the device is supported you have the firmware to enable it: 1. `fwupdmgr refresh` 2. `fwupdmgr update`

Comment: What do you mean by "In 20.04 was not really efficient, working maybe 2 times out of 10"? Did fingerprint sensor work in 20.04? What release are you using now?

Answer (score 0):

In my ThinkPad X1 Yoga 3rd gen, the fingerprint reader name is “Synaptics, Inc.”. The following workaround works perfectly with this fingerprint reader but this is not specific to this model. It should work with other fingerprint readers too.

```
lsusb
```

[list devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V82ne.png)

Once you see the name of the fingerprint reader in the list, run the following commands:

```
sudo apt remove fprintd
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:uunicorn/open-fprintd
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install open-fprintd fprintd-clients python3-validity
fprintd-enroll
```

And that is all. Now your fingerprint reader is ready to be used on your Ubuntu laptop.

However, your device is still not ready for using the fingerprint reader for login. To enable the fingerprint reader for login, run the following command:

```
sudo pam-auth-update
```

It will ask for your account password. Enter the password in the terminal. Then you will see a window like this:

[select fingerprint using space bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtGIs.png)

Once this is complete, you can go to your “Users” setting on Ubuntu and then click on the “Fingerprint Login” option. There you will get an option to scan a new fingerprint for login.

[Add your fingerprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgNwK.png)

Solved issue following the blog post.
https://www.rupokify.com/tech/how-to-enable-fingerprint-login-on-ubuntu/

Comment: I have tried the above work around several times and have not been able to get it to work for me what am I missing? X1 yoga 3

Comment: If you broke the login (password input field disappears immediately) --> ``sudo apt install fprintd libpam-fprintd``

Answer (score 0):

Fingerprint authentication is enabled by default using Ubuntu 22.04 and Yoga X1 (as well as other Thinkpads). Just open your user settings and add your fingerprint. In more details explained [here](https://itsfoss.com/fingerprint-login-ubuntu/).

However, via fingerprint your keyring cannot be opened. [That is only possible with your password](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gdm/-/issues/613). So, essentially logging in via fingerprint is worthless.